# Vagrant Powershell issue with Hyper-V VM (vagrant version 1.8.4) *Permission denied*

Tags: powershell, vagrant, virtual-machine, puppet, hyper-v

I have a Hyper-V VM constructed with Vagrant 1.8.4, and I am trying to use the "vagrant powershell" command to start a script that was provisioned (using puppet) onto the VM. Some directories are easily accessed, such as C:\users\vagrant. I have complete control of this folder and all subsequent directories. Whenever I try to start the script, or even access some folders using the 'dir' command, I get an error that states "permission denied".

Here is the output for a simple "vagrant powershell -c 'C:\provision\shell'" command:

```
vagrant : The following WinRM command responded with a non-zero exit status.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The following W...ro exit status.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!
dir 'C:\provision\shell'
Stdout from the command:
Stderr from the command:
#< CLIXML
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04"><S S="Error">dir : Access to the 
path 'C:\provision\shell' is denied._x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">At line:1 char:40_x000D__x000A_</S><S 
S="Error">+ $ProgressPreference='SilentlyContinue';dir 'C:\provision\shell'_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">+         
                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">    + CategoryInfo          : 
PermissionDenied: (C:\provision\shell:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessExcepti _x000D__x000A_</S><S 
S="Error">   on_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error"> 
_x000D__x000A_</S></Objs>
```

If someone could help me figure out why I am getting these "permission denied" errors, that would be GREAT!

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, I could never find a reason why I am unable to access the shared folder remotely... I **was** however able to provision a script that copied the contents of the shared folder to a directory I do have access for. 
A bit ugly and inelegant, but it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with this one was that I was attempting to connect to the VM using "vagrant powershell" while in a remote-pssession. Windows was not passing my credentials because I was remoted in and attempting to access the SMB folder back to the VM host, which was NOT my local machine. The SMB shared folder is a 'symlink' and that is where tripping occurred. Access might have been granted if I had a delegated token (e.g. using CredSSP).

As stated in my comment, I **was** able to copy the contents of the shared folder via a provisioned PowerShell script. Ugly, but works.

Thanks to codekaizen for helping me formulate a response (credit where credit is due).